# How to insert an HTML table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to write a JS function called `addMultiTable(rows, cols)` that will create a multiplication table with 4 rows and 8 columns, and append it after the header:`<h1>Multiplication Table</h1>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Multiplication Table</h1>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you? Where did you get stuck? What did you attempt? What went wrong? *How* was it "wrong"?

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far? And where exactly you have problems? Are you familiar with the DOM as well as manipulating it through JavaScript? If not, you should first read more about the topic as no one is going to provide you a whole solution if you haven't made any effort.

Comment: I have worked on it and it kinda worked but still a problem. I will post it in a new Question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    function addMultiTable(rows, cols) {
    var myHeader = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
    var table = document.createElement("table");

        
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++ ) {
       var row = document.createElement("tr");
       table.appendChild(row);
       for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.innerHTML = (i+1)*(j+1);//value inside cells
        row.appendChild(cell);
           
       }
       table.appendChild(row);
    }
    myHeader.appendChild(table);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you, remember there are a few ways to solve this problem

```
function addMultiTable(rows, cols) {
var table = document.createElement("table"),
    elem = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0],
    i = 1,
    j = 1,
    val = 0;

for( i; i <= rows; i++ ) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for( j; j <= cols; j++) {
        var col = document.createElement("td");
        val = i * j;
        col.innerHTML = val;
        row.appendChild(col);
    }
    j = 1;
    table.appendChild(row);
}
elem.parentNode.insertBefore(table,elem.nextSibling);
}
addMultiTable(4,8);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it needs this part `val = i*j`?

Comment: It's the value for each table cell. Current row number multiplied by current column number

Comment: And `.insertBefore` is `undefined`.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery .append() function to append the table to the div.

You can find the demo of the .append() in `https://jsfiddle.net/stktjo67/`

And Here is the documentation link for .append() `http://api.jquery.com/append/`